# REDUX-SAGA ERROR _this2.props.dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Привет всем. 
После использование thunk прочитал про

> Redux-saga — это альтернативный подход к организации сайд-эффектов.
>   Вместо того, чтобы диспатчить функции, которые обрабатываются
>   redux-thunk-ом, вы создаёте сагу, которая собирает всю логику
>   обработки внутрь себя. В отличие от thunk-ов, которые выполняются,
>   когда вы их диспатчите, саги запускаются при старте приложения и как
>   бы «работают в фоне». Саги слушают все экшены, которые диспатчит стор,
>   и решают, что делать с ними.
>
> И у саг в редаксе два преимущества по сравнению с thunk-ами: — Они
>   позволяют организовывать сложные последовательности сайд-эффектов — И
>   они очень легко тестируются

Хочу применить Redux-saga

```
function loadApi() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(resolve('1 sec'));
        }, 3000);
    });
}

// worker Saga: будет запускаться на экшены типа `USER_FETCH_REQUESTED`
function* fetchUser(action) {
    try {
        const msg = yield call(loadApi);
        yield put({type: "ACTIVATE_GEOD", title: msg});
    }catch(e){
        console.log('error')
        yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED",  title: msg});
    }
}
function* mySaga() {
    yield takeEvery("ACTIVATE_GEOD", fetchUser);
}
```

ну и привязка Saga:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();


function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
    const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
        //Redux middleware provides a third-party extension
```

point between dispatching an action, and the moment it reaches the reducer.
            //Redux middleware is nothing more than a function 
which is invoked after an action is dispatched but before a 
reducer takes care of the action
            //applyMiddleware(ping)
        )
        return store;
    };
    var store = configureStore();

```
sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga);
```

Теперь когда кликаю по кнопке

```
 <button onClick={() =>this.props.dispatch(   
{ type: 'ACTIVATE_GEOD', title: 'UPS SAGA' }   )}>
                         REDUX-SAGA   Click Me!
                    </button>


    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators({activateGeod, closeGeod}, dispatch)
    }
```

Получаю ошибку

> _this2.props.dispatch is not a function
>   Помогите мне пожалуйста получить рабочий пример от SAGA чтобы я смог дальше использовать его мозможности .

Comment: не совсем понятно откуда у вас взялось `_this2.props.dispatch`. Либо это `_this.props.dispatch` либо `this.props.dispatch`

Comment: насколько видно вы не правильно использовали функцию в компоненте. Ваш коннект метод инжектирует в пропсы компонента не диспатч функцию а `activateGeod, closeGeod`. Попробуйте вызвать в компоненте `<button onClick={() =>this.props.activateGeod()>
                         REDUX-SAGA   Click Me!
                    </button>`